# How to get multiple checkbox values in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I have following code of five checkboxes with similar `name=check[]`

```
<input type='checkbox' value='1' name='check[]'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='1' name='check[]'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='1' name='check[]'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='1' name='check[]'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='1' name='check[]'/>
```

I am sending this data to PHP page using form and extracting this data in php as following

```
<?php
$check=$_POST['check'];
print_r($check);
?>
```

Output for three checked checkboxes will always be as following even If i check checkbox no 1,2,5 or  1,3,4

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
)
```

**For Example:**

If there are total five checkboxes and i only checked 1st and 3rd checkbox then my output must be

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [3] => 1
)
```

or

```
Array
    (
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 1
        [4] => 0
        [5] => 0
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser will send the values of the checked checkboxes, right now your values are always 1.

Try changing your code to:

```
<input type='checkbox' value='1' name='check[]'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='2' name='check[]'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='3' name='check[]'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='4' name='check[]'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='5' name='check[]'/>
```

Comment: I can't change the value, its like true/false option, so value=1 means true

Comment: Why can't you change the value? If the id of the checkbox exists, the value is true, otherwise it is false. Your browser will not make a difference based on the order of your checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

get all the values from the checkboxes like you are doing, than do a for loop untill the length of array and if particular value of any key is 1 than you can do process on it as you like for example

```
 $data = array(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
);
 $output=array();
 for($i=1; $i<=count($data); $i++)
 {
    if($data[$i])== 1)
      $output[] = $data[$i];
 }
 print_r($output);
```

i hope this will solve your problem.

Regards